# Cross Browser Unselectable/Undraggable Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For some reason my images are still able to dragged even though I've implemented a relevant code for this issue. I need to know why my images are still allowed to be dragged.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m3wQc/3/ (Updated JSFiddle)

Javascript: (All Caps removed)

```
#("#TESTDIV").bind("mousedown", function(event) {
$(document.body).addClass("UNSELECTABLE");
    ...                 
});
#(document.body).bind("mousemove", function(event) {
    /* SOME CODE */
});
#("#TESTDIV").bind("mouseup", function(event) {
$(document.body).removeClass("UNSELECTABLE");
    ...                 
});
```

Comment: `Javascript` is Case-sensitive. Not sure why it's all capitalised...

Comment: Please don't capitalize JavaScript. You also are using # instead of $

Comment: why is this code supposed to do? Thenere's no #testdiv, NEVER use capital-only, except for define globals/constants !

Comment: @NickR So if I remove all the capital letters the code will function?

Comment: you gave fiddle but, there is pseudo code there? Provide what have you tried actually

Comment: `#(document.body)` - should be `$` not `#` etc. `REMOVECLASS` is not the same as `removeClass`

Comment: You have a few `CSS` errors too. It's always advisable to use a debugger like `Firebug` or `Chrome` developer tools when writing `Javascript`

Comment: You can't prevent images from being copied/saved anyway.

Comment: @NickR I removed the caps

Comment: Also you have duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load Jquery in your fiddle and use a script like this:

```
$(".UNSELECTABLE").mousedown(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HSbf4/

This has all CSS removed to show you that none is needed with this approach. Should run in older Browsers too this way.

Comment: So that's all the Javascript needed for this to work?

Comment: Yep! This blocks the mousedown event for all Elements with class UNSELECTABLE. So for the upper part it blocks the whole div and in the bottom part it blocks just the img.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check the jQuery API to align your code with the correctly spelled/cased APIs. JavaScript is case sensitive and your methods are all incorrect. This should get you going:

```
$('#testdiv').on('mousedown', function (event) {
    $('body').addClass('unselectable');             
});
```

I'd use `.on()` instead of `.bind()` as `.on()` is the preferred method.

Comment: You haven't loaded the jQuery library. You also have `...` in your code which will cause an error.

Comment: And the `<body>` then has a class called `unselectable`, it now works.